# SQL pull data based on date range

Tags: sql

I am pulling data that contains two columns with dates. I only want to return rows of data where date one, `last_update` occurred within 7 days of date two, `program_end_day`.

I have tried several variations of the following but this returns rows where `last_update` occurred years before the `program_end_day`

```
and last_updated >= DATEADD(DAY, 7, program_end_day)
```

What I expect to be returned are rows in which the `last_updated` date is equal to `program_end_day` or within 7 days of `program_end_day`. Something like

| program_end_day | last_updated |
| --- | --- |
| 2024-3-13 | 2024-3-15 |
| 2024-3-20 | 2024-3-26 |

I have found answers to similar questions but instead of pulling the date from a column its a date the user inputs manually or using the `today` variable

Comment: Please tag the specific DBMS you're using, as answers (especially with date functions) can vary materially between each of them.

Comment: DateAdd only works in  SQL Server and MySQL so that narrows it down. In Postgres, the functionality of the DATEADD() function can be achieved via the “+” operator. In Oracle the DateAdd function has different parameters. DateAdd (Date, Format, Days, Months, Years)

Comment: @BartMcEndree Hmm, not sure I agree. How did you reach that conclusion? `DATEADD` also exists in the lexicon for [Snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/dateadd), and [Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEADD_function.html), [Microsoft Access](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dateadd-function-63befdf6-1ffa-4357-9424-61e8c57afc19) as well, all with the same parameters.

Comment: @BartMcEndree, let OP tell us. Too often users try to use functionality from other dbms's than used.

Comment: I believe we are using MySQL

Comment: You *believe* it's MySQL??? You should know. If you don't, aks someone who knows. For otherwise, how do you know what syntax is available and which docs to look up?

Comment: If you're using MySQL, `select version();` will return the version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM PulledData
WHERE  last_updated BETWEEN
 program_end_day 
 AND 
 DATE_ADD(program_end_day, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

[MySQL fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PEvAqgZV)

[SQL Server fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iv9r6gvA)

Comment: Since this has both -7 & 7 would this show 'last_updated' dates that occurred 7 days before to 7 days after 'program_end_day' (a 14 day window)? I want to make sure that the 'last_updated' occurred on same date as 'program_end_day' or within 7 days after.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In that case you want 

last_updated between program_end_day AND DATEADD(DAY, 7, program_end_day)

Comment: Like this without any other indicators of DATE?

and last_updated BETWEEN program_end_day AND DATEADD(DAY, 7, program_end_day)

Comment: For MySQL the syntax is DATE_ADD(program_end_day, INTERVAL 7 DAY)

Comment: In MySQL you don't need a function for this. Just use standard date arithmetic: `program_end_day + INTERVAL 7 DAY`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select from your_table
where last_update >= DATE_SUB(program_end_day,INTERVAL 7 DAY)
and last_update <= DATE_ADD(program_end_day,INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```